# FTP "put" not copying file to remote host when ran from shell script but copies the file to remote host when ran manually

Tags: ftp, file-copy

```
ftp -n ${FTP_HOST} << STOP
    user ${FTP_USERNAME} ${FTP_PASSWORD}

    binary
    lcd ${FTP_FROM_DIR}
    cd ${FTP_TO_DIR}
    put ${reportFileName}   
STOP
```

That is my code which is not successfully copying the file to remote host but using it manually it successfully copies the file to remote host.

When ran from a script, "(local-file) usage:put local-file remote-file" appears in the console.

what could be the problem?

Comment: What does the String Expansion print for from and to dir?

Comment: from: /home/893591/SI/data/mpsftp/krnu003/forftp
to: /home/893591/SI/data/mpsftp/krnu003

I'm just actually testing my ftp code within the same server, given that the remote server is not yet accessible. So what I am trying to do here is that transferring the file to another folder within the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect part of your issue is with the way you're constructed your heredoc. Try it like so:

```
$ ftp -n ${FTP_HOST} << STOP
user ${FTP_USERNAME} ${FTP_PASSWORD}

binary
lcd ${FTP_FROM_DIR}
cd ${FTP_TO_DIR}
put ${reportFileName}   
STOP
```

If you truly want those spaces/tabs in the command then you'll need to change to this form of the heredoc:

```
$ ftp -n ${FTP_HOST} <<-STOP
    user ${FTP_USERNAME} ${FTP_PASSWORD}

    binary
    lcd ${FTP_FROM_DIR}
    cd ${FTP_TO_DIR}
    put ${reportFileName}   
STOP
```

Whenever you have spaces/tabs within your heredoc you need to make use of the `<<-` for to tell the shell to strip the leading spaces/tabs out prior to running the commands that are contained within.

#### A sidebar on using echo

When you're parsing variables within scripts and you innocently use `echo` to print messages you're typically getting more than just the string you're interested in. `echo` will also include a trailing newline character. You can see it here in this example:

```
$ echo $(echo hi) | hexdump -C
00000000  68 69 0a                                          |hi.|
00000003
```

The `0a` is the ASCII code for a newline. So you'll typically want to disable this behavior by using the `-n` switch to `echo`:

```
$ echo -n $(echo hi) | hexdump -C
00000000  68 69                                             |hi|
00000002
```

Or even better upgrade to using `printf`.

#### References

- [How to use ftp in a shell script](http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html)

Comment: tried this one but got the same result

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg - and if you put the actual values into the heredoc vs. using the variables, does it still not work? Try this just to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: it worked! i've used the actual values into the heredoc..

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg -  yes but how are they being sourced into the script that's ultimately running the above `ftp`?

Comment: I declared them in the script. I tried adding "tr -d '\r'" in their initialization, and it worked.. it's carriage return is the culprit after all.. do you know how carriage returns' presence in the variables can be prevented?

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg - I'd have to see the rest of the script to understand what you're up to.

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg - what does the command `print` do in `getValue()` func?

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg - I'd also suggest using `set -x` to enable debugging of the script. You'll often quickly see your issue w/ verbose debugging output. I suspect that should be `echo`. Also the `$(echo `getValue ..`) is what's causing the extra `\r`. Take out the `tr -d '\r'` on those lines and change `echo` to `echo -n`.

Comment: i really don't know what it does, they just gave it to us and want us to use those functions for uniformity..

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg - no problem. Try changing the echo as I suggested, does that  get rid of the need for `tr`?

Comment: i think not, because before, i was not using the echo.. however, the value set was erroneous without it and the tr.. I searched for answers and that's the answer I got..

Comment: i am really suspecting that \r's appear whenever I remove the ^M's inside the script using SecureCRT

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg - ah the plot thickens. This script is a mess. I hope I'm not offending you, but it's pretty awful code.

Comment: no, not at all.. it's not really the code that i will use, the code's like that because of the testing.. i cannot get it to run.. due to my frustration, i added this code and that, tried that, tried this.. XD

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg - That's usually how these coding projects go 8-). Well it's pushing almost 5am, I think you have a handle on your issue. The FTP Q you originally asked has been answered and you're onto other problems now 8-).

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg - BTW, if you want to debug a block of code you can wrap `set -x` at the beginning of it, and put `set +x` at the end to stop the debugging.

Comment: @KevinMacaraeg - you can mark this as the accepted A so that other's know your issue's been resolved.